# Generating PDF With Doxygen

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-addtogroup

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 with Doxygen 1.8.17. I have also installed latex.

I can get the .html file just fine and it's populated with all the documentation, but converting the outputted latex files through both commands:
latex refman
pdflatex refman

Results in "file 'float.sty' not found". I traced back to the file location where it should be, but the file there is non-existent. "xcolor.sty" also seems to be missing, among possibly others.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like an incomplete LaTeX installation, just install the missing packages. Which LaTeX version did you use?

Comment: I figured it out: I had to run "sudo apt-get update -y", "sudo apt-get install -y doxygen-latex" then I was able to run the other commands (answered in "how to get a single pdf document from Doxygen")

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y doxygen-latex
```

then I was able to run the other commands (answered in "how to get a single pdf document from Doxygen")

Thanks Albert for the help!

Comment: I'm amazed that such an `apt-get exists`, as it is for an apt-get **not possible ** which packages a user will use. With a lot of effort the `apt-get` can probably figure out which packages doxygen uses. I would more go for a standard LaTeX installation.

Comment: This may be a special case for that set of packages since a good portion of Doxygen functionality is based on what you can do with the LaTeX. Though I can't say I know much about how apt-get works as I'm still pretty new to Linux

Comment: I had the same problem, and `apt install -y doxygen-latex` worked for me.